# Cómo puedo recibir un ID de campo de un formulario y eliminar ese registro de una tabla en MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, formularios

Tengo una tabla en MySQL llamada `trabajos` que tiene 3 campos (`Id_trabajo`, `Nombre_Trabajo` y `Costo`), de igual manera muestro dicha tabla en mi html:

[image: Tabla con los tres campos + columna con botón Editar + columna con botón Eliminar]
quiero que al hacer click en *Eliminar* sobre cualquier registro, éste se elimine de la base de datos y que obviamente ya no salga,
¿cómo le hago?

Éste es mi código de mi modal, para eliminar:

```html
<!--MODAL PARA ELIMINAR UN REGISTRO DE LA TABLA Y DE LA BD-->
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="eliminar_modal.php">
<div id="myModal3" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content"> 
      <!--Cabecera del modal-->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Elimnar Trabajo</h4>
      </div> 
      <!--Contenido del modal-->
      <div class="modal-body">
          <p><h1>¿Esta seguro?</p></h>
          <p><h3>Se borrara permanentemente!</p></h3>

      <!--Final del modal-->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Eliminar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 </form>
```

Les dejo mi código PHP que hace la consulta

```php
<?
$conexion= mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "registros");
if($conexion)
{


  //Variables
  $Id_trabajo = $_POST['txt_id'];
  $Nombre_Trabajo = $_POST['txt_nombre'];
  $Costo=$_POST['txt_costo'];


//realiza la consulta
  $consulta= "DELETE FROM trabajos WHERE Id_trabajo='$Id_trabajo'";



//para ejecutar consulta
  $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion ,$consulta);


  if ($resultado) {   ?>

      <div class="alert alert-success">
      <strong>Datos guardados correctamente!</strong> 
      <a href="consulta_lista.php" class="alert-link">Volver</a>
      </div>

      <?php  }

      else { ?>

      <div class="alert alert-warning">
      <strong>Error al guardar los datos!</strong>
      <a href="consulta_lista.php" class="alert-link">Volver</a>
      </div> 

      <?php } 


      }
      else{ 
        echo ""; 
      }
        mysqli_close($conexion);   
      ?>
```

Comment: ¿Donde específicamente estás teniendo alguna dificultad con tu código?

Comment: No me hace nada, no me elimina nada

Comment: @Rms En qué lugar del formulario estás enviando el valor del id `txt_id` seleccionado? ¿Qué valor estás recibiendo en el PHP? Por favor intenta depurar el código, por ejemplo imprimiendo en pantalla el valor de `$consulta` y mostrando en tu pregunta qué valor tiene y qué valor debería tener. Por otro lado, tené en cuenta que este código tiene algunos problemas de seguridad y permite la inyección SQL. Una vez que soluciones el problema de esta pregunta, deberías leer [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/18233/127).

Comment: Mira aquí: [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Tiene excelente sugerencias para ayudarte a averiguar en qué lugar específicamente está el problema. Y también te ayudará a proveernos con un código mas reducido con el cual será mas fácil ayudarte.

Comment: Es que en mi tabla en mysql tengo un campo que se llama (Id_trabajo) el cual lo puse auto-increment, entonces yo tengo un boton que al hacer click sale un modal, que tiene dos campos de texto uno llamdo(txt_nombre) y el otro (txt_costo) los cuales envian los datos a la tabla y en automatico se pone el Id que sigue,por eso ya no puse el campo (txt_id) en mi modal, pero ahora para eliminar un registro como se identifica para borrar? por eso deje el campo txt_id,

Answer (score 1):

Deberías de depurar un poco tu código PHP, al igual que te ha dicho Mariano en uno de los comentarios, deberías leer [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php/18233#18233).

En tu código usas 3 variables, sin embargo en la consulta solo empleas una, con lo cual solo haría falta mantener: (He añadido la función mysqli_real_escape_string para evitar inyecciones SQL)

```
  //Variables
  $Id_trabajo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['txt_id']);
```

El nombre que se pone entre corchetes, no es por gusto, debe hacer referencia a algo, por ello, debes incoporar en el formulario un campo que nos transmita la ID que queremos borrar.

```
<input type="hidden" name="txt_id" id="id_borrar" value=""/>
```

Te la he colocado:

```
<!--MODAL PARA ELIMINAR UN REGISTRO DE LA TABLA Y DE LA BD-->

<div id="myModal3" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
     <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="eliminar_modal.php">
<input type="hidden" name="txt_id" id="id_borrar" value=""/>
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content"> 
      <!--Cabecera del modal-->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Elimnar Trabajo</h4>
      </div> 
      <!--Contenido del modal-->
      <div class="modal-body">
          <p><h1>¿Esta seguro?</p></h>
          <p><h3>Se borrara permanentemente!</p></h3>

      <!--Final del modal-->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Eliminar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Dependiendo del elemento que queramos borrar, tendremos que cambiar la id en el modal, por eso en el botón de eliminar deberás incoporar lo siguiente y dónde te he colocado ID BORRAR CON ECHO, imprimir la id del elemento:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3" data-idborrar="ID BORRAR CON ECHO">Eliminar</button>
```

Por último usamos jquery para transmitir del botón de Eliminar al modal la ID a borrar.

```
<script>    
$('#myModal3').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
      var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
      var recipient = button.data('idborrar') 

      var modal = $(this)
      modal.find('.modal-body #id_borrar').val(recipient)
    })
</script>
```

Con esto, te debería funcionar el código, todo esto se puede complicar más, haciendolo con AJAX para que no recargue la página cada vez que borramos un elemento, incluso hacer que desaparezca de la tabla.

Comment: Tengo dudas, el código del boton que me pusiste va adentro del modal, con el cual se elimina, o va en mi tabla para que en todos los registros diga eliminar? y otra cosa para que se ejecute el script tengo que poner una libreria? es que no me hace nada, gracias

Comment: Mira te cuento porque tengo el "txt_id"                                                             Es que en mi tabla en mysql tengo un campo que se llama (Id_trabajo) el cual lo puse auto-increment, entonces yo tengo un boton que al hacer click sale un modal, que tiene dos campos de texto uno llamdo(txt_nombre) y el otro (txt_costo) los cuales envian los datos a la tabla y en automatico se pone el Id que sigue,por eso ya no puse el campo (txt_id) en mi modal para agregar un nuevo registro, pero ahora para eliminar un registro como se identifica para borrar? por eso deje el campo txt_id

Comment: El botón tienes que ponerlo en tu tabla como si fuera el de eliminar, lo modificas a tu gusto. Para que funcione el código jquery tienes que importar la librería de jquery. Se identifica por la id, el botón lleva "impresa" la id, se la pasa al modal y el modal la envía a tu código php para borrarla.